# How do I authenticate on a page that requires JavaScript by using HttpClient?

Tags: java, authentication, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to programmatically authenticate a url and get the response using Apache Commons httpclient.
The response code is 200 however the i am getting a response with the a sign on page. I want to deep dive in to the sign on page and get the response.

I am noticing that the cookies are blank when i try printing using the following code:
Cookie[] cookies = httpclient.getState().getCookies();

The response has the following message:
"Your browser does not have JavaScript enabled. This feature is needed to support XXXX's Windows Single Sign-On (WSSO). Please contact your 
PC support person or call"

Pls help.

Comment: Maybe you could use HtmlUnit : http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/  It's a headless java browser with javascript support.

Comment: You can accepts and promote my answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you set the following cookie policy:

```
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.cookie-policy", CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

From the link http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html
Browser compatibility:  This implementation strives to closely mimic the (mis)behavior of common web browser applications such as Microsoft Internet Explorer and Mozilla FireFox.